# using grep with the OS X top command

Tags: macos, grep

I have found [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/165214/52224), and mine is similar but relates to the OS X (10.7.5) version of the top command.

The version of the command I am using is:

```
top -o cpu -O th|grep Chrom
```

I am trying to find all the processes that are run by Google Chrome, when I just do top -o cup -O th the google Chrome processes get truncated to Goole Chrom, that is why I am greping for Chrom not Chrome.

I have also tried this version of the command, with even worse results.  The command hangs and does not return anything at all:

```
top |grep Chrom
```

I am encountering two issues with the version of the command that actually runs:

1. the command above takes very long to start (in the order of 20 seconds), it starts immediately without piping to grep.

### Why the delay?

2. the output is not greped, I am getting screwed up output with line breakes here and there and all the processes including the ones that I am greping for.  Clearly I am either greping incorrectly or piping incorrectly or missing another command.

[image]

### What should the correct format of the above command be?

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The top command is really intended for interactive use, not for scripting, and may or many not use stdout and stderr in the way you're expecting.  Try the ps command in a loop instead, e.g.

```
while true ; do
    clear
    ps auxwww | grep Chrome
    sleep 1
done
```

or possibly without the w flags.